# Is there a dry-top for the freestyle snorkel?

Tags: equipment, training, swimming, freestyle

I own a [Finis Freestyle snorkel](http://www.finisinc.com/equipment/technical-products/snorkels/freestyle-snorkel.html). Along with it I had bought a [snorkel dry top](http://www.finisinc.com/equipment/technical-products/snorkels/snorkel-dry-top.html) as well; only to, later, discover that it only works with the regular snorkels and not with the freestyle version. Does anyone know of a product that can water-seal my snorkel?

The only catch is that the freestyle snorkel's opening facing downwards so the dry top needs to be designed according to that.